# How can you make an image background just in the corner?

Tags: css, background, background-image

I’m wondering how I can make a background only show up in the corner (and the other 3 corners around the content) like shown in the picture below… namely:

- I obviously can’t have a big image and the content inside of it, so I assume it’ll have to be 4 separate images
- I’m assuming it has to be an image because you can’t draw that kind of shape in css
- I don’t think there’s a way to have an image that the background is transparent, right?

[image: background image]

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next for one corner:

```
div.image {
    background-color: #fff; /* Set default background color, same that background's base color */
    background-image: url("corner.png"); /* Set transparent image for corner */
    background-position: right top; /* Set positioning */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Disable multiple background images  showing */
}
```

Or this for multiple backgrounds:

```
div.image {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image:
        url("corner1.png"),
        url("corner2.png"),
        url("corner3.png"),
        url("corner4.png");
    background-position:
        right top, /* Set positioning for corner 1 */
        right bottom, /* Set positioning for corner 2 */
        left bottom, /* Set positioning for corner 3 */
        left top; /* Set positioning for corner 4 */
    background-repeat:
        no-repeat,
        no-repeat,
        no-repeat,
        no-repeat;
```

More informathion you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_backgrounds_and_borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Also you can draw same shape by using SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial

Comment: Wonderful, thanks, I’ll try that. What if I need an image like that in each corner? Like on the corners of a piece of paper. Can I have multiple background-positions?

Comment: @blubberbo, I have updated the code for multiple background.

Answer (score 2):

**Use three CSS properties:**

1. `background-image` with multiple border images like `background-image: url(IMAGE1), url(IMAGE2), url(IMAGE3), url(IMAGE4)`
2. Position the images through `background-position` like `background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right`
3. Specify the size of images through `background-size` like `background-size: 200px 80px`